# Adding title to autoplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggfortify

I used `autoplot` to create simple `lm` plots by using the code below. But when I use `autoplotly` to make an interactive plot, the title disappears that's generated by `autoplot`, and even if I use `ggplot2::ggtitle`, the title still doesn't show up. How can I fix this? The CSV can be downloaded from [here](https://app.box.com/s/08be32mxvwcrhpk0xusxbyz3oh2ho4ix).

```
# Read file
df = read,csv(Mean_SWE.csv)
# Run the model
Model = lm(formula = SWE ~ Mean.Z + Intensity.mean, data = df)
# Plot
lm.plot.rsd = autoplot(Model, label.size = 3, which = 1) +
  theme_bw()
autoplotly(lm.plot.rsd) +
  ggplot2::ggtitle("Residuals vs Fitted")
```

[image]

Comment: Try `autoplotly(lm.plot.rsd + ggplot2::ggtitle("Residuals vs Fitted"))` Add the title to the ggplot object, not the plotly object.

Comment: @MrFlick, still doesn't work

Comment: Then can you provide a reproducible example that we can copy/paste to test?

Comment: @MrFlick, done, please check if the code is reproducible now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`autoplot` creates `ggmultiplot` object (`lm.plot.rsd`) which is stripped of all of its titles in autoplotly in order to call plotly functions properly. The solution is to pass `ggplot` object to `autoplotly`. So, take the `ggplot` that you need out of `ggmultiplot`, like this `lm.plot.rsd@plots[[1]]`

Try this:

```
df = read.csv("Mean_SWE.csv")
# Run the model
Model = lm(formula = SWE ~ Mean.Z + Intensity.mean, data = df)
# Plot
lm.plot.rsd = autoplot(Model, label.size = 3, which = 1) +
  theme_bw()
autoplotly(lm.plot.rsd@plots[[1]]) +
  ggplot2::ggtitle("Residuals vs Fitted")
```